# Because this module of magento 2 does not work?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am new in magento 2, following a tutorial in the official documentation try to create a simple view, but when I log in my route throws me error 404

This is the structure of my directory

[image]

This is what I have in my files

view.php

```
<?php

namespace Learning\HelloPage\Controller\Page;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class View extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */

     protected $resultJsonFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory)
    {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $data = ['message' => 'Hello World'];
        return $result->setData($data);
    }

}
```

routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="Learning" frontName="test">
            <module name="Learning_HelloPage" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_HelloPage" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 
    'Learning_HelloPage',
   __DIR__ 
);
```

In addition to this in the console I run the following command for the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

After all this when entering the next path on my server

> http://localhost/magento/test/view/page

I get 404 error, but in the title that followed, it is exactly like that. What error do I have and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The url path should be

> http://localhost/magento/test/page/view

And make sure you run this command to install your module:

```
php bin/magento s:up
```

And then you can check your module is enabled or not by this:

```
php bin/magento module:status Learning_HelloPage
```

Cheers